# Crystal Reports : This group section cannot be printed

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm currently modifying an existing report and replacing the data source used in the report.  The reason I'm not creating a new report is because the report is laid out exactly how I would like it to be laid out.  I've updated every field with the new data source fields and checked that the formulas are all correctly formatted.

Everytime I attempt to view the report (I'm using the Crystal Reports tool in VS 2010), I get the error "The group section cannot be printed because its condition field is nonexistent or invalid.  Format the section to choose another condition field."

I've read another question from stackoverflow but still can't seem to find out what is wrong with my report.

First of all, why doesn't Crystal tell you more specifically what is wrong?

Any suggestions or hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought is that you didn't update the Groups correctly when you switched backends.  Go into your **Group Expert**.  Do you see any groups simply labeled with question marks?  If so, there's your problem.  Go into the options for that group and choose an appropriate grouping field.

Also, use the **Database->Verify Database** command to look for other possible errors.

As for your question about Crystal's design, I believe that it does give *reasonably* accurate error messages, especially considering everything that can go wrong with any one report.

Comment: There weren't any question marks in the Group Expert but after I changed what it was grouping by, the report now previews... thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I guess what I meant by being more specific was which group was there an issue with... as oppose to just saying there is an issue with one of the groups